# Problems launching QB program on a separate machine

Tags: c#, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I'm making a program for a friend, but when I try to launch this on his machine, I get this error. I tried launching this on a separate machine as well, and this same error happens.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C693D8F1-180B-4F82-B735-8F511B566718} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

When I try to run it on my PC, where I made this app, it runs.

I changed the platform target to x86, and when I debug on a separate machine it takes me to this line, with that error.

```
QBSessionManager sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();
```

Help please.

Comment: Is your COM object registered on the other machine? Sounds like it isn't..

Comment: Hi, im not sure how to check that, im trying to look for something online for registering COM object's. 
I thought it was a lib, or dll file that may of been missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run the QBFC installer on the other machine? I seem to recall getting this error when I forgot to do that on a client's PC. That would take care of registering QBFC COM objects.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, no I haven't, I'll give it a try when I get home. It sounds like you may be right but I always though the dll and lib files took care of that.

Comment: Thank You so much, I just tested it on my laptop, and it works. Thank you so much.